# OpenBox - what is dock in ObConf?

Tags: linux, openbox

I try to customize OpenBox. In ObConf i see tab Dock and there's set position top left. But i don't see anything there.

So, **what is** that **Dock**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dock is a place where you could place "things". [More info](http://urukrama.wordpress.com/openbox-guide/#Launchers).

Comment: Following your link i've found also these links: http://urukrama.wordpress.com/openbox-faq/#dock, http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#How_do_I_make_my_dockapps_appear_in_order_when_I_start_Openbox.3F. You could add them into answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

From [Openbox guide](http://urukrama.wordpress.com/openbox-guide/):

> Unlike Fluxbox, Blackbox or Icewm, Openbox does not come with a panel. If you do want to use a panel, you’ll have to add one yourself, but, since you have a wide selection of panels to choose from, this allows you to have everything just the way you want it.

Comment: Please don't post quotes without proper attribution. I've edited it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think he might not be referring what a dock actually is, I think it's more like why is the dock option there when openbox doesn't load up anything really, not even the bg and youhave to install more dependencies to set up a bg, a dock or a menu bar.